# SQLite проблема с запросами

Tags: c, sqlite

Делаю запрос в базу такой:`char *sql = "SELECT * from CITY";` - все работает отлично, но когда пытаюсь сделать `sprintf(sql, "SELECT * from %s", TABLE_NAME);` - программа вылетает.

Comment: `from` в строке `sprintf` куда делся? И что такое `TABLE_NAME`?

Comment: исправил, TABLE_NAME - просто константа с именем таблицы

Comment: Второй вопрос: `sql` так и остался `char *`?

Comment: что значит остался?

Comment: как описана переменная sql? char sql[ЗНАЧЕНИЕ] или char *sql? Второе, если переменная sql описана как массив, то все равно лучше использовать snprintf.

Comment: описана так же как и в первом случае - char *sql

Comment: @UjinUkr Ну вот потому и вылетает.

Comment: У SQLite есть свои собственные [printing functions](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
char *sql = "SELECT * from CITY";
sprintf(sql, "SELECT * from %s", TABLE_NAME);
```

Вы просто не выделили память для строки. Вот здесь:

```
char *sql ...
```

объявляется переменная типа указатель, которой присваивается адрес константной строки `"SELECT * from CITY"`. Попытка модифицировать константную строку приведёт к ошибке. Вы должны или выделить достаточно неконстантной памяти в буфере сразу:

char sql[SOME_SIZE];

Или гарантировать выделение нужного количества памяти, например, так:

```
char *sql = NULL;
int size = 0;
const char fmt[] = "SELECT * from CITY";
const char TABLE_NAME[] = "CITY"; 
size = vsnprintf( sql, size, fmt, TABLE_NAME);
if (size < 0) /* ошибка */;
++size;
sql = malloc(size);
if( !sql ) /* ошибка */;
size = vsnprintf( sql, size, fmt, TABLE_NAME);
if (size < 0) { 
    free( sql );
    /* ошибка */
}
/* ... что-то делаем ... */
free( sql );
```